# Exclude a woocommerce product category from wordpress global search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to exclude some post category from the wordpress search results :

```
function SearchFilter($query)
{
    if ($query->is_search)
    {
        $query->set('cat', '-709,-710,-614');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

My problem is that it doesn't work for woocommerce categories and products are not filtered.
How can I filter some woocommerce categories too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace your category. hope this help you.

```
function wpse188669_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

   if (

       ! is_admin()

&& $query->is_main_query()

&& $query->is_search()

   ) {

       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'product' ) );

       // set your parameters according to

     // https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

       $tax_query = array(

           array(

               // likely what you are after

               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',

               'field'   => 'slug',

               'terms'   => 'category-2',

               'operator' => 'NOT IN',

           ),

       );

       $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse188669_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: It works for woocommerce products, but wont it filter also posts with the same terms ?

Comment: You want to post filter should be change taxonomy