# Exclude category from search results

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I do have one question.
On wp I have uncategorized category with a lot products,
On small-glasses-page I want to hide that uncategorized category when someone searching for exp shot glasses, just show shot glasses, not wine glasses (**uncategorized**).
I tried this but this is removing from whole site uncategorised category

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'uncategorized' ), // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );


    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162232/exclude-categories-from-search-query   I think helpful for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303827/exclude-a-woocommerce-product-category-from-wordpress-global-search-results#:~:text=I'm%20using%20this%20code,pre_get_posts'%2C'SearchFilter')%3B